# Delete the email that was used to create the account and login using an alias in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have a Gmail account created using my name as `firstname.lastname@gmail.com`. But I don't like it, and I want to login using `firstnamelastname@gmail.com`. Surely this is obviously possible (by using the feature "Add another account you own"). Also, `firstnamelastname@gmail.com` can be made the default sending address. But in the Gmail page, on the top right corner, clicking on the user icon shows that old `firstname.lastname@gmail.com` as my email address. I don't want that.

So is there any way to remove the email address that was originally used to create the email account (`firstname.lastname@gmail.com` in my case), and use an alias (`firstnamelastname@gmail.com`) as the email address? In fact, I want to do this only because I don't like to see `firstname.lastname@gmail.com` as my email address on the top right corner, and in all other places where my email address is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately once you create your Google Account using the dots in the username you will not be able to convert it to an account without the dots. However, you should still be able to log in with or without the dots in your email as well as send and receive mail to both addresses.

> ## Remove dots from my email address
>
> If you have a dot in your email address, you don't need to change anything. You'll get any emails people send to your address even if they don't include the dots.
>
> Messages sent to sportsfan@gmail.com and sports.fan@gmail.com will go to the same place. Learn more about getting someone else's mail.

Sources:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8158
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/gmail/ax6WMJB4gkA

Comment: I knew that already. I just don't want to see my email address with dot anymore, that's it. I think that should be an easy thing to provide to the users- to be able to delete the email that was used to create the email account. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> In fact, I want to do this only because **I don't want to see** <sup>1</sup> firstname.lastname@gmail.com as my email address on the top right corner.

<sup>1</sup>: Emphasis mine.

## Short answer

Customize the CSS of the Google account dropdown card by using Stylebot.

## Explanation

Google doesn't offer a way to end-users to change the email address displayed on the Google account dropdown card, but you could hide it by yourself by using the browser web developer tools, a userscript through a bookmarklet or a extension like Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey but the easier way is by using Stylebot, a Google Chrome extension.

Stylebot open a floating side panel that allows you to apply a custom CSS by selecting the web page element directly on the page and hide it by clicking a button.

I rarely use Stylebot, but should use it more frequently as I very frequently take screenshots and have to edit the image to hide personal information. I just think that it also could be useful in situations like the described on this question.

### Instructions

1. [Install Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha)
2. Open or refresh the Gmail web page
3. Open Stylebot
4. If necessary, move the side panel to the left
5. Select your email on the Google account dropdown card
6. On the Stylebot side panel, go to the Layout & Visibility section, and click the Hide button.

[image: Hide button on Stylebot floating side panel]

Comment: That's fantastic answer! I will give it a shot. But, in the long run, I don't think I will push it that far just to not see that pesky little dot.

Comment: BTW, will I have to change it every time I go to Gmail page?

Comment: No, styles that you set are saved. You could turn on/off, edit or delete those styles.

Comment: Actually, by *"I don't want to see ..."* I meant *"I don't like the email address with dot in it"*. But using your technique all I can do is hide the email address altogether, but it is still there, and shown right when logging in, and also in all other places where my email address is to be displayed.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to make it clear what you meant.

Comment: I thought I made it clear enough, but after your answer/comment I see there is still scope for understanding otherwise. Edited.